# Registration an end-user by openid connect specification

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-provider, openid-connect

I can't found specification for registration the end-user in openid connect.

Maybe, you know how do it?

I have some idea, but I looking for official answer.

Comment: I don't think openid connect covers user registration at all.

Comment: New OIDC [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-prompt-create-1_0.html) (in work) may help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That part is implicitly included when they talk about [Authentication of the End-User](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authenticates).

When your provider attempts to Authenticate the End-User (by displaying a login form), then if the user has no account you can:

- Show the registration form in the same view as the login.
- Put a link somewhere in the view (ex. "Create account").

In both cases, you'll have a "next" or a "redirect_to" (call it whatever you like) that will have the OpenID Authentication Request URL-safe encoded (or an OAuth2 Authorization Request).

See an example:

```
# Auth Request from some client.
/openid/authorize?client_id=123&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=abcdefgh

# Because user is not logged, you attempts to Authenticate it.
/login?next=%2Fopenid%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3D123%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252F%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%26state%3Dabcdefgh

# Because user is not registered. You provide a link like this.
/register?next=%2Fopenid%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3D123%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252F%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%26state%3Dabcdefgh

# After registration. The flow will continue.
```

Hope you understand it. Greetings.